# How to inject services into methods in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to understand dependency injection in AngularJS.

Right now, I'm trying to inject `$interpolate and $eval` into my controller, but [reading the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interpolate) didn't clarify because I don't have a good foundation on Angular.

Take the following code that demonstrates the issue I don't understand:

```
var module = angular.module('ngAppDemo',[ ]);

module.controller('ngAppDemoController', function($scope, $parse) {
  $scope.a = 1;
  $scope.b = 2;
  $scope.myHTML = '{{a}}';

});
```

Can someone help me understand how to inject and `$interpolate` the myHTML string? Or if interpolation is not correct in evaluating that string, what is? It's a weird case, but I'm just trying to learn right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're very close. just need to declare it as module dependency and add to function parameters. (i think this should work)

```
var module = angular.module('ngAppDemo',['$interpolate' ]);

module.controller('ngAppDemoController', function($scope, $parse, $interpolate) {
  $scope.a = 1;
  $scope.b = 2;
  $scope.myHTML = '{{a}}';

});
```

i've been declaring controllers and injection in this way:

```
angular.module('app').controller(
        'generator', 
        ['myService', '$http', '$scope', '$interpolate', generator]
);

function generator(myService, $http, $scope, $interpolate) {
    $scope.foo = 'bar';
}
```

where the controller object (in my case *generator*) is passed in to the module declaration

Comment: how is `$interpolate` being injected in the second example?

Comment: just like all the other services.. added $interpolate in.

Comment: May I edit my question to include how to inject $eval as well? I tried to include `$eval` in the array and as an argument to the function on JSfiddle, but my program just died: http://jsfiddle.net/dMp55/1/

Comment: +1 on @SonicSoul method of setting up a controller - this protects you from Angular minification woes.  Side note, do you even have to declare `$interpolate` as a dependency on the `ngAppDemo` module?  Can't you just pass it to your controller like you're doing on the bottom.